# header is overlapped by sticky navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<section class="bg-secondary-dark py-2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="mailto: " class="mr-3 text-white"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook mr-3 text-muted"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-0 bg-white justify-content-between **fixed-top**">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

> this is sticky bootstrap navbar. i downloaded bootstrap and js using npm and didn't used custom css

Comment: can you try to add some padding?

Comment: Just add some margin-top for the sticky navbar and it should do

Comment: @Jithin i applied padding as well but still navbar is overlapped over above section

Comment: @SARAN SURYA i applied margin-top and its fine but when i scroll down the margin is taking space

Comment: @parveen if the margin top is taking up space, then try adding a onscroll listner and the scroll location, like if the scroll is in the top of the page we can add the margin, else we remove the margin, That approach should work.